# Templatic responsive v 1.0 theme error after installation

Tags: wordpress, themes

I installed templatic responsive 1.0 theme and i get this error below right after installation and activation. Anyone with a possible clue as to how to resolve this error
Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

```
Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressss/wp-content/themes/Responsive/monetize/manage_settings/manage_custom_usermeta.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressss\wp-content\themes\Responsive\monetize\manage_settings\function_manage_settings.php on line 641

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressss/wp-content/themes/Responsive/monetize/manage_settings/manage_custom_usermeta.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressss\wp-content\themes\Responsive\monetize\manage_settings\function_manage_settings.php on line 641
actually the code on line 641 is :
```

...

```
include_once(TT_MODULES_FOLDER_PATH.'manage_settings/manage_custom_usermeta.php');
/* Custom User meta Field  EOF*/
```

There is no file called *manage_custom_usermeta.php* in the folder manage_settings
Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I usually get errors like so. Not sure where it is coming from but try reinstalling the theme if it is a theme. Another suggestion is to double check your functions.php file for spaces and code errors. Last suggestion is to find TT_MODULES folder and see if the file lies in there. I do not have the theme so I can not dive into it but try the above and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you log in to Templatic [member area](http://templatic.com/members/member.php) and download the newest version of the theme - this shouldn't be happening (I'm using that particular theme on a personal site). If problems do continue just create a ticket in our Helpdesk and we'll sort it out as fast as possible

Cheers
Vedran from Templatic